# Is it possible to give certain users a custom embed color in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to give myself a custom embed color but is this possible? I have this code right now:

```js
let color = message.member.displayHexColor;
if (color == '#00000') color = message.member.hoistRole.hexColor;
let set = db.fetch(`g_${message.guild.id}`);
if (message.channel.id === set) {
 var serverIcon = message.guild.iconURL();
 const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle(message.author.tag)
  .addField('Message:', message.content)
  .setColor(message.member.displayHexColor)
  .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL())
  .setFooter(
   `Server: ${message.guild.name} || UserID: ${message.author.id} || Members: ${message.guild.memberCount}`
  );
 client.guilds.cache.forEach((g) => {
  try {
   client.channels.cache.get(db.fetch(`g_${g.id}`)).send(embed);
  } catch (e) {
   return;
  }
 });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ternary operator to check if the member is you.

```js
// for a single person
.setColor(message.author.id === 'Your ID' ? 'special hex color (or rgb value)' : color)

// for multiple
.setColor(['Your ID', 'Second ID', 'etc...'].includes(message.author.id) ? 'special hex color' : color)
```

Comment: Is it also possible to add a second ID?

Comment: switch `message.author.id === 'Your ID'` to `['Your ID', 'Second ID'].includes(message.author.id)`. You can add as many IDs to the array as you want.